# Find X/Y of an HTML element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I find the XY coordinates of an HTML element (DIV) from JavaScript if they were not explicitly set?

Comment: closed as duplicate as per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha

Answer (score 34):

Here's how I do it:

```
// Based on: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html
var getCumulativeOffset = function (obj) {
    var left, top;
    left = top = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            left += obj.offsetLeft;
            top  += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }
    return {
        x : left,
        y : top
    };
};
```

Comment: I think I prefer your idea of returning an object over Peter-Paul Koch's choice of returning an array in his original solution.

Answer (score 9):

That can be tricky depending on browser and version.  I would suggest using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and the positions plugin.

Comment: Most of the positions plugin is now part of jQuery core. So you can just do $(element).offset({relativeTo: "body"}) - and it will give you the top and left of the object relative to the body.

Comment: Excellent, I haven't downloaded jQuery in a few months, good to know they rolled it in.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a library such as Prototype or jQuery, or you can use [this handy function](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html):

It returns an array.

```
myPos = findPos(document.getElementById('something'))
x = myPos[0]
y = myPos[1]

function findPos(obj) {
  var curleft = curtop = 0;
  if (obj.offsetParent) {
    curleft = obj.offsetLeft
    curtop = obj.offsetTop
    while (obj = obj.offsetParent) {
      curleft += obj.offsetLeft
      curtop += obj.offsetTop
    }
  }
  return [curleft,curtop];
}
```

Comment: You should give the attribution to quirksmode.org, that function looks very familiar.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, here's a recursive version:

```
function findPos(element) {
  if (element) {
    var parentPos = findPos(element.offsetParent);
    return [
      parentPos.X + element.offsetLeft,
      parentPos.Y + element.offsetTop
    ];
  } else {
    return [0,0];
  }
}
```

Comment: parentPos.X should be parentPos[0], 
parentPos.Y should be parentPos[1]

Answer (score 2):

You can add two properties to the `Element.prototype` to get top/left of any element.

```js
window.Object.defineProperty( Element.prototype, 'documentOffsetTop', {
    get: function () { return this.offsetTop + ( this.offsetParent ? this.offsetParent.documentOffsetTop : 0 ); }
} );

window.Object.defineProperty( Element.prototype, 'documentOffsetLeft', {
    get: function () { return this.offsetLeft + ( this.offsetParent ? this.offsetParent.documentOffsetLeft : 0 ); }
} );
```

Here's a demo comparing the results to jQuery's `offset().top` and `.left`: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/3G7EZ/

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you need it for, and such things are always relative (screen, window, document). But when I needed to figure that out, I found this site helpful:
http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/anchorposition/source.html

And I also found that the tooltip plugin someone made for jQuery had all sorts of interesting insight to x,y positioning tricks (look at its viewport class and the underlying support jQuery provides for it).
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/