# How do you get the co-ordinates of en element from browser window top and left in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get the element co-ordinates relative to browser window.
How do you get that in javascript ?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160144/find-x-y-of-an-html-element-with-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element relative to the browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element-relative-to-the-browser-window)