# How can I get an object's absolute position on the page in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, offset

I want to get an object's absolute x,y position on the page in Javascript.  How can I do this?

I tried `obj.offsetTop` and `obj.offsetLeft`, but those only give the position relative to the parent element.  I guess I could loop through and add the parent's offset, and its parent's offset, and so on until I get to the object with no parent, but it seems like there should be a better way. Googling didn't turn up much, and even SO site search isn't finding anything.

Also, I can't use jQuery.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/dyanamically-reterive-html-element-x-y-position-with-javascript

Comment: Another Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160144/find-x-y-of-an-html-element-with-javascript

Comment: site search fails again!  thanks guys, i figured this had to have come up before

Comment: Up-voted for asking a REAL (no frameworks) JavaScript question. The answer by @Sk8erPeter is the way to go.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

```
var cumulativeOffset = function(element) {
    var top = 0, left = 0;
    do {
        top += element.offsetTop  || 0;
        left += element.offsetLeft || 0;
        element = element.offsetParent;
    } while(element);

    return {
        top: top,
        left: left
    };
};
```

(Method shamelessly stolen from PrototypeJS; code style, variable names and return value changed to protect the innocent)

Comment: i love comment below the code :D

Comment: Note that the element must be styled relative, absolute or fixed, I think?

Comment: Not the most efficient method. I would consider it a hack. Sk8erPeter's answer is more adequate

Answer (score 161):

**I would definitely suggest using [element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect).**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect

> ### Summary
>
> Returns a text rectangle object that encloses a group of text
>   rectangles.
>
> ### Syntax
>
> `var rectObject = object.getBoundingClientRect();`
>
> ### Returns
>
> The returned value is a [TextRectangle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMClientRect) object which is the union of the
>   rectangles returned by [getClientRects()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getClientRects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element.getClientRects) for the element, i.e., the CSS
>   border-boxes associated with the element.
>
> The returned value is a `TextRectangle` object, which contains read-only
>   `left`, `top`, `right` and `bottom` properties describing the border-box, in
>   pixels, with the top-left relative to the top-left of the viewport.

Here's a browser compatibility table taken from the linked MDN site:

```
+---------------+--------+-----------------+-------------------+-------+--------+
|    Feature    | Chrome | Firefox (Gecko) | Internet Explorer | Opera | Safari |
+---------------+--------+-----------------+-------------------+-------+--------+
| Basic support | 1.0    | 3.0 (1.9)       | 4.0               | (Yes) | 4.0    |
+---------------+--------+-----------------+-------------------+-------+--------+
```

It's widely supported, and is really easy to use, not to mention that it's really fast. Here's a related  article from John Resig: http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome/

You can use it like this:

```
var logo = document.getElementById('hlogo');
var logoTextRectangle = logo.getBoundingClientRect();

console.log("logo's left pos.:", logoTextRectangle.left);
console.log("logo's right pos.:", logoTextRectangle.right);
```

Here's a really simple **example**: http://jsbin.com/awisom/2 (you can view and edit the code by clicking *"Edit in JS Bin"* in the upper right corner).

Or here's another one using Chrome's console:
[image: Using element.getBoundingClientRect() in Chrome]

#### Note:

I have to mention that the `width` and `height` attributes of the `getBoundingClientRect()` method's return value are `undefined` in Internet Explorer 8. It works in Chrome 26.x, Firefox 20.x and Opera 12.x though. Workaround in IE8: for `width`, you could subtract the return value's right and left attributes, and for `height`, you could subtract bottom and top attributes ([like this](http://jsbin.com/awisom/3/edit)).

Comment: offsetLeft returns different values in ie and firefox, ie didn't include the margins and ff also gave incorrect result but this solved it

great got what i needed, thanks, works perfect

Comment: Is this a completely different use case? scroll the page down and check your values again... `getBoundingClientRect()` is for the position relative to the scrolled window... your top value will change to negative as you scroll past the logo.

Comment: @jondavidjohn Sure, but that can be easily adjusted by adding `window.pageYOffset` (or, if you really need IE8 compatibility, [`(window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollY#Notes)). Same for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I think you should edit the answer to include this page offset snippet in a way that will answer the original OP question. Getting to be the most upvoted answer brings some responsibility with it ;)

Comment: @user123444555621 Should I add the `window.pageYOffset` to `bottom`, too? And `window.pageXOffset` to `right`, too? In order to have consistent `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` values?

Comment: This method is, in my opinion, meant to solve exactly this issue. So +1 from me, I hope the OP changes the accepted answer because, although the other one is good, this one is better.

Comment: In my case, `getBoundingClientRect` returned wrong offset from top. Suggestion of @eyelidlessness is working.

Comment: But `getBoundingClientRect` doesn't return `absolute` positions of element's `x`, `y`

Comment: @user123444555621 This statement is not correct, while it may work for most use cases, `window.pageYOffset` will not work if your element is in a scrollable element that is not the body of the page

Comment: The question asked for "relative to page", not "relative to viewport".