# Getting absolute position of an element relative to browser

Tags: javascript, css, positioning, offset

I have a div set to the css class float with float being:

```
.float {
display:block; 
position:fixed; 
top: 20px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 1999999999;
}
* html .float {position:absolute;}
```

This class causes the element to stay in a fixed position on the page (the *html part is to make it work in IE). I am using javascript to shift the position of the element horizontally and vertically.

I need to get the absolute position of the div relative to the browser window in javascript (how many pixels from the top and left of the browser window the div is). Right now, I am using the following:

```
pos_left = document.getElementById('container').offsetLeft;
pos_top = document.getElementById('container').offsetTop;
```

The code above works for IE, Chrome, and FF, but in Opera it returns 0 for both. I need a solution that works for all of those browsers. Any ideas?

Btw: Keeping tracking of the changes made by javascript is possible, but that is not the solution I am looking for due to performance reasons. Also, I am *not* using jquery.

Comment: +1 for not using jQuery if you don't need to and mentioning it :)

Comment: Carefull with that number at the `z-indez` ;). Don't go that high if you don't need to.

Comment: Does using such high z-indices degrade performance?

Comment: See this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480133/how-can-i-get-an-objects-absolute-position-on-the-page-in-javascript/16626843#16626843

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use items style element;

```
<div id="container" style="top: 20px;left: 0px;z-index: 1999999999;">
```

You can get it with element style attribute;

```
var top = parseInt(document.getElementById('container').style.top.split('px')[0], 10); // This row returns 20
```

You can use **top, left, width, height etc...**

Comment: Why do you use eval ? This is not needed at all

Comment: Still the same thing. Says 0 for the offset :/

Comment: @Fabien because style.top attribute is splitted and its returns string.
@user396404 can u post code any web page or this page?

Comment: Ah nm, got it work using this. Just modified it a bit and made the following function:

function styleval(v)
{
 
 v = v.split('px');
 return v[0]*1;
 
}

then I use pos_top = styleval(document.getElementById('container').style.top);

Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: parseInt(document.getElementById('container').style.top) does the trick.

Answer (score 11):

I've had a similar question before, and looking through the blogs, the websites and this solution from stackoverflow, I've realized that a one size fits all solution is nowhere to be found! So, without further ado, here is what I've put together that gets the x,y of any element through any parent node, including iframes, scrolling divs and whatever! Here ya go:

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = 0;
    var curtop = 0;
    if(obj.offsetLeft) curleft += parseInt(obj.offsetLeft);
    if(obj.offsetTop) curtop += parseInt(obj.offsetTop);
    if(obj.scrollTop && obj.scrollTop > 0) curtop -= parseInt(obj.scrollTop);
    if(obj.offsetParent) {
        var pos = findPos(obj.offsetParent);
        curleft += pos[0];
        curtop += pos[1];
    } else if(obj.ownerDocument) {
        var thewindow = obj.ownerDocument.defaultView;
        if(!thewindow && obj.ownerDocument.parentWindow)
            thewindow = obj.ownerDocument.parentWindow;
        if(thewindow) {
            if(thewindow.frameElement) {
                var pos = findPos(thewindow.frameElement);
                curleft += pos[0];
                curtop += pos[1];
            }
        }
    }

    return [curleft,curtop];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A variation on user1988451's answer that I have tested cross-browser. I found their answer did not address scroll width (so I added the check for obj.scrollLeft), and behaved differently in FF and Chrome until I added the checks for thewindow.scrollY and thewindow.scrollX. Tested in Chrome, IE, Safari, Opera, FF, IE 9-10, and IE9 with 8 and 7 modes. Please note that I have not tested its behavior with iframes:

```
function findPos(obj, foundScrollLeft, foundScrollTop) {
    var curleft = 0;
    var curtop = 0;
    if(obj.offsetLeft) curleft += parseInt(obj.offsetLeft);
    if(obj.offsetTop) curtop += parseInt(obj.offsetTop);
    if(obj.scrollTop && obj.scrollTop > 0) {
        curtop -= parseInt(obj.scrollTop);
        foundScrollTop = true;
    }
    if(obj.scrollLeft && obj.scrollLeft > 0) {
        curleft -= parseInt(obj.scrollLeft);
        foundScrollLeft = true;
    }
    if(obj.offsetParent) {
        var pos = findPos(obj.offsetParent, foundScrollLeft, foundScrollTop);
        curleft += pos[0];
        curtop += pos[1];
    } else if(obj.ownerDocument) {
        var thewindow = obj.ownerDocument.defaultView;
        if(!thewindow && obj.ownerDocument.parentWindow)
            thewindow = obj.ownerDocument.parentWindow;
        if(thewindow) {
            if (!foundScrollTop && thewindow.scrollY && thewindow.scrollY > 0) curtop -= parseInt(thewindow.scrollY);
            if (!foundScrollLeft && thewindow.scrollX && thewindow.scrollX > 0) curleft -= parseInt(thewindow.scrollX);
            if(thewindow.frameElement) {
                var pos = findPos(thewindow.frameElement);
                curleft += pos[0];
                curtop += pos[1];
            }
        }
    }

    return [curleft,curtop];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find clues here : http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/ArticlePageOffset
But I think you'll need to add the parents' offsets to have the right value.

Answer (score 1):

I use this for PhantomJS rasterization:

```
function getClipRect(obj) {
  if (typeof obj === 'string')
    obj = document.querySelector(obj);

  var curleft = 0;
  var curtop = 0;

  var findPos = function(obj) {
    curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
    curtop += obj.offsetTop;
    if(obj.offsetParent) {
      findPos(obj.offsetParent);
    }
  }
  findPos(obj);

  return {
    top: curtop,
    left: curleft,
    width: obj.offsetWidth,
    height: obj.offsetHeight
  };
}
```