# How can I create a static <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like create a static `<div>`, if user uses the scroll, the `<div>` must be still.

Context: I am working in a project and I need three static components, I managed to make two components but as I am using JSF, Primefaces and Bootsfaces (bootstrap and JQuery), the third component must be different. The thrid component must be a typical `<div>`.

My code:
1. html:

```
<div id = "divProyecto">
    ....
 </div>
```

2. css:

```
#divProyecto{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border: solid #222222 1px;
}
```

3. js (I found this code, but doesn't work):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#divProyecto').scrollToFixed();
});
```

This image resume all: http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/9622798algo.gif
The image show as the black boxes don't move, but blue box move with scroll.

Thanks you!

Comment: static mean fixed?

Comment: Yes! see the gif image, my problem is the blue box.

Comment: I think you'll find the solution has been addressed here: [how can I stick the div after scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496240/how-can-i-stick-the-div-after-scrolling-down-a-little)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position Fixed elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783299/position-fixed-elements)

Comment: and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158559/how-to-fix-a-header-on-scroll and... lmgtfy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `position: fixed;`

And specify the

```
top: 100px;
left: 100px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/fwkWG/

Comment: Perfect! Its is the solution! THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

position: fixed;

It cant work in IE 6, as IE 6 not support position: fixed.Google chrome ,Firefox AND IE with version > 6 should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed` and then position on the screen as you see fit.

```
    #divProyecto{
        background-color: blue;
        height: 50px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        border: solid #222222 1px;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
```

The above will position your div on the top left corner of the window.

Answer (score 0):

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 50px; /* your choice */
margin: 0;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you. To OP: my post is CSS style for your div `#divProyecto`.