# While styling the web using css whenever I used to fix the position of the header its width decreases. How can I solve this?

Tags: html, css, position

I am using the code below to fix the position of the header bar,but this code is disturbing other components of **HTML**.

```
    .container header{
        position:fixed;
    }
```

Whenever I write this code about **position**, the **width** of the **header** decreases and it also covers menu section which is below it.

Some portion of menu is then not able to be seen.
How to style this so that other components of **HTML** stay with its own *styling*

Comment: [That's how fixed elements work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) ... what do you want to happen ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position Fixed elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783299/position-fixed-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set an element to fixed or absolute position it no longer attempts to fill the width of the parent element. It will take up the width and height of it's content. These elements are also taken out of the normal document flow so they no longer take up any space.

Using `position: fixed;` will align the element to the browser viewport as it's containing element. Since a fixed position element doesn't take up any space the reset of the content will behave as if it's not on the page and position itself accordingly. The fixed position element will then end up overlaying that content.

To remedy the overlay affect you will need to add padding or margin to the element that is being overlaid equal to the height (or more) of the fixed position element. Padding is typically used as margins collapse.

### Before Sizing and Padding

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Something should go here.
</header>
<main>
  <p>
    Content after fixed position element.
  </p>
  <p>
    Content after fixed position element.
  </p>
</main>
```

### With Sizing and Padding

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* -or- left: 0; right: 0; */
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
main {
  padding-top: 30px; /* -or- margin-top: 30px; -watch out for collapsing margins- */
}
```

```html
<header>
  Something should go here.
</header>
<main>
  <p>
    Content after fixed position element.
  </p>
  <p>
    Content after fixed position element.
  </p>
</main>
```