# ASP fixed Header

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a GridView in a div on my HTML-Code like this:

```
   <div class="container" style="width: 80%; height: 800px; overflow: scroll">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="40" AllowSorting="True"
            AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" EnableModelValidation="False" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" CssClass="mydatagrid"
            PagerStyle-CssClass="pager" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerGrida1" RowStyle-CssClass="rows"
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="Black">
```

The div makes it already scrollable but I also need a fixed Header of the Grid. What I tried with CSS doesnt work out...

I tried thi for the container:

```
.container
        {
            overflow: scroll;
        }
        .container table th
        {
            position: relative;
        }
        .container table tbody
        {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
```

And this with the Gird:

```
.headerGrida1
{
    background-color: #4a708b;
    font-family: Calibri;
    color: White;
    border: none 0px transparent;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;

}
```

But nothing seems to work...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158559/how-to-fix-a-header-on-scroll

Answer (score 1):

Below is the good solution that will fixed header with vertical and horizontal scroll bars

http://www.dotnetbull.com/2011/11/scrollable-gridview-with-fixed-headers.html

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a way to do t just with CSS?

That's what I get when switching Position=absolute or = fixed.

[image]

The only thing is that it has to be above the first row otherwise nobody would see the rwos anymore.

[image]
Maybe there is simple solution, too?
Another Problem is that he width of the header is now different to the columns