# Having a section first on top before the navigation bar, and when scrolled the navbar will stick on top

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

This is what I want to do. An Image section on top before the navigation bar. After scrolling on the image section on top the navigation bar will stick on top. How can I do that?

[See the Attached Photo for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn5Nb.png)

Comment: What you tried so far? Can you please share your code?

Comment: Please go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158559/how-to-fix-a-header-on-scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the element to `position: sticky` and then give it the position you want it to stick at (`top: 4rem`, etc.).  It will have relative position within its block, then and then will stick in position as the block is scrolled past.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :))