# Once I scroll down, how do I get my navbar to stay at the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a portfolio website and I've run into an issue I need help with. It's a single page parallax site. When the user enters text appears saying welcome, the nav bar is out of site.

Once the user scrolls down to see the rest of my page the nav bar appears. I would like to nav bar to stay at the top of the page once the user scrolls down enough to the point where the nav bar gets to that position. Basically how this website does it http://findmatthew.com/.

I have tried wrapping the nav bar in a new div and using position: sticky, top: 0; but the styling of the nav bar disappears.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #222;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #1f2733;
  margin-top: -22px;     /* <<<--- This moves the entire nav box up or down!!  */
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  float: center;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 190px;
  position: relative;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;   /*Changing the font of the nav bar*/
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #a23131;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #a23131;
    margin-top: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;

  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: use this example and add css anitation:  https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/lJoyk

Comment: I believe "position: sticky" is what you are looking for. Beware that it is not compatible with older browsers (like IE).

Comment: > I have tried wrapping the nav bar in a new div and using position: sticky, top: 0; but the styling of the nav bar disappears.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix a header on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158559/how-to-fix-a-header-on-scroll)

Answer (score -1):

```css
/* The navigation bar */

.navbar {

  overflow: hidden;
  
  background-color: #333;
  
  position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  
  top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
}
```

Comment: There was no need to create snippet.

Answer (score -1):

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```