# Div element's height on the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I find what the height of a div is from the top of the page? I want to make a div appear when the scroll is that height. Does anyone happen to know that?

Comment: I think you are looking for: [How to get scrollbar position with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/how-to-get-scrollbar-position-with-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get an object's absolute position on the page in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480133/how-can-i-get-an-objects-absolute-position-on-the-page-in-javascript)

Comment: thank you for your answers. I found my solutions.