# Getting the Starting left position and top position of an element

Tags: javascript, css

In javascript I have a problem with a script I am writing. I need to be able to get the starting top and left positions of an html object like a table or an image that are defined in the CSS.

When I define the left(20px) and top(20px) offsets for the table I run the javascript console built into chrome and do parseInt(document.getElementById('component1').style.left)  to see if it will give me the magnitude of the offset as a number. However, it returns NaN. I'm guessing because the browser isn't initializing these values(I thought setting it explicitly in the CSS, that the browser would)

Any ideas as to how I can get around this?

Comment: use document.getElementById('component1').offsetLeft or .offsetTop

Answer (score 2):

Is jQuery an option?  If so:

```
var offset = $("#component1").offset;
//use offset.left, offset.top for whatever you need
```

If not, you can do this by looping, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160144/find-x-y-of-an-html-element-with-javascript/160428#160428).

Comment: the looping answer didn't work :\ I will see about getting jQuery.

Comment: got jquery .offset.left and .offset.top are undefined.

Comment: @AFK it's `.offset().left` see https://api.jquery.com/offset/