# How to get top and left style property values in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a little bit of Javascript that almost works correctly.  Here's the code:

```
function toggle(curlink) {
 curlink.style.backgroundColor = curlink.style.backgroundColor == "yellow" ? "transparent" : "yellow";
 var maindiv = document.getElementById("grid");
 var links = maindiv.getElementsByTagName("a");
 var list = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
  var link = links[i];
  if (link.style.backgroundColor == "yellow") {
   list += ("," + parseInt(link.style.left, 10) + "-" + parseInt(link.style.top, 10));
  }
 }
 document.theForm.theList.value = list.substring(1);
 return false;
};

window.onload = function() {
 var links = document.getElementById("grid").getElementsByTagName("a");
 for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
  links[i].onclick = function() { return toggle(this); }
 }
};
```

The issue is with line #9; it only works when I specify values for the top and left style property of every link in the array.  How do I get the top and left style property values (or X and Y coordinates) of each link in the array with Javascript when those values aren't given?

Also, what would the code above look like in jquery?  Not that it's needed - I just want to reduce the code a little and dabble in the jquery framework (I'm a Javascript newbie).

Thanks in advance,
Dude-Dastic

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160144/find-x-y-of-an-html-element-with-javascript

Comment: I never saw that post.  Nice reference, though.  Thanks Diodeus!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`link.offsetLeft` and `link.offsetTop`. More about finding position [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html). They'll be positions relative to the offsetParent, but the link shows a way to get position relative to the document.

[offsetParent](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html) will evaluate to the body if the parent elements are positioned statically or there's no table in the parent hierarchy. If you want a position other than body then update the parent of the links to have a non-static position, perhaps `relative`

I'm not familiar with JQuery so I can't help there

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Bob.  I'm gonna check it out.

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't go so well.  The values appear to be relevant to the document and not the parent.

Comment: @Dude-Dastic Just offsetTop and offsetLeft by themselves will give results relative to offsetParent if that's what you need

Comment: @Bob  I tried your previous suggestion.  However, I still get incorrect results.  offsetTop and offsetLeft by themselves still return values relevant to the document.

Comment: @Bob  Oops!!! You were right.  My tests were wrong.  Everything is working perfectly now.  Thanks!

Comment: offsetParent sometimes evaluates to the document. See http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html Change the parent of the links to position:relative or something other then static...Let me edit to update

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery might look something like this. Untested.

```
$(function(){
    // Get all <a> descendents of #grid 
    var $anchors = $('#grid a');
    // Bind a click handler to the anchors.
    $anchors.click(function(){
        var $clickedAnchor = $(this);
        var coordinates = [];
        // Set the background color of the anchor.
        $clickedAnchor.css('background-color', $clickedAnchor.css('background-color') == 'yellow' ? 'transparent' : 'yellow');
        // Loop through each anchor.
        $anchors.each(function(){
            var $anchor = $(this);

            if ($anchor.css('background-color') == 'yellow') {
                var offset = $anchor.offset();
                coordinates.push(offset.left + '-' + offset.top);
                // Or maybe..
                // var parentOffset = $('#grid').offset();
                // coordinates.push((offset.left - parentOffset.left) + '-' + (offset.top - parentOffset.top));
            }
        });

        $('#theList').val(coordinates.join(','));

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, CalebD.  Unfortunately, it didn't work.  Coordinates were never captured, and there was no toggle effect.