# how to get the top left x and y coordinate using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that we can get width and height using clientWidth and clientHeight, however how do I figure out the top left x and top left y position of an element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function findPosX(obj)
  {
    var curleft = 0;
    if(obj.offsetParent)
        while(1) 
        {
          curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
          if(!obj.offsetParent)
            break;
          obj = obj.offsetParent;
        }
    else if(obj.x)
        curleft += obj.x;
    return curleft;
  }

  function findPosY(obj)
  {
    var curtop = 0;
    if(obj.offsetParent)
        while(1)
        {
          curtop += obj.offsetTop;
          if(!obj.offsetParent)
            break;
          obj = obj.offsetParent;
        }
    else if(obj.y)
        curtop += obj.y;
    return curtop;
  }
```

[Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/dynamically-retrieve-html-element-x-y-position-with-javascript)

[Find X/Y of an HTML element with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160144/find-x-y-of-an-html-element-with-javascript)

These two links should be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

To get the top you need to add the `offsetTop` of the element and the element's `offsetParent`'s `offsetTop`. Do this all the way up the DOM to the `document`. That accounts for absolute, relative and fixed positioning. To get the left, do the same thing with `offsetLeft`.

These two functions add two properties to `Element`, `documentOffsetTop` and `documentOffsetLeft`, that will get top/left of any element:

```js
window.Object.defineProperty( Element.prototype, 'documentOffsetTop', {
    get: function () { 
        return this.offsetTop + ( this.offsetParent ? this.offsetParent.documentOffsetTop : 0 );
    }
} );

window.Object.defineProperty( Element.prototype, 'documentOffsetLeft', {
    get: function () { 
        return this.offsetLeft + ( this.offsetParent ? this.offsetParent.documentOffsetLeft : 0 );
    }
} );
```

This demo shows several combinations of element layout, comparing `documentOffsetTop` with jQuery's `offset().top`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/3G7EZ/

Script:

```js
window.Object.defineProperty( Element.prototype, 'documentOffsetTop', {
    get: function () { 
        return this.offsetTop + ( this.offsetParent ? this.offsetParent.documentOffsetTop : 0 );
    }
} );

var line = document.getElementsByClassName( 'grid-line' )[0],
    grid = document.getElementById( 'grid' );

for( var index = 2; index < 100; index++ ) {
    var copy = line.cloneNode();
    copy.textContent = ( index * 10 );
    grid.appendChild( copy );
};

var offset = document.getElementById( 'absolute' );
offset.textContent = 'absolute: ' 
    + offset.documentOffsetTop + ', $' 
    + $( offset ).offset().top;

offset = document.getElementById( 'static' );
offset.textContent = 'static: ' 
    + offset.documentOffsetTop + ', $' 
    + $( offset ).offset().top;

offset = document.getElementById( 'static2' );
offset.textContent = 'static: ' 
    + offset.documentOffsetTop + ', $' 
    + $( offset ).offset().top;

offset = document.getElementById( 'relative' );
offset.textContent = 'relative: ' 
    + offset.documentOffsetTop + ', $' 
    + $( offset ).offset().top;

offset = document.getElementById( 'fixed-side' );
offset.textContent = 'fixed/absolute (side): ' 
    + offset.documentOffsetTop + ', $' 
    + $( offset ).offset().top;

offset = document.getElementById( 'fixed-top' );
offset.textContent = 'fixed/absolute (top): ' 
    + offset.documentOffsetTop + ', $' 
    + $( offset ).offset().top;

offset = document.getElementById( 'fixed-bottom' );
offset.textContent = 'fixed/absolute (bottom): ' 
    + offset.documentOffsetTop + ', $' 
    + $( offset ).offset().top;

offset = document.querySelectorAll( '#relative-wrapped-absolute div' )[0];
offset.textContent = 'absolute/relative/static (absolute/relative wrapped): ' 
    + offset.documentOffsetTop + ', $' 
    + $( offset ).offset().top;

offset = document.querySelectorAll( '#static-wrapped-static div' )[0];
offset.textContent = 'static (static wrapped): ' 
    + offset.documentOffsetTop  + ', $' 
    + $( offset ).offset().top;
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="static" class="offset">0</div>
<div id="static2" class="offset">0</div>
<div id="static-wrapped-static"><br /><div class="offset">0</div></div>
<div id="absolute" class="offset">0</div>
<div id="relative" class="offset">0</div>
<div id="fixed-side" class="offset">0</div>
<div id="fixed-top" class="offset">0</div>
<div id="fixed-bottom" class="offset">0</div>
<div style="position: relative;"><div id="relative-wrapped-absolute"><div class="offset">0</div></div></div>

<div id="grid"><div class="grid-line">10</div></div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {padding-left: 12px;}

#absolute {
    top: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}

#relative {
    top: 150px;
    position: relative;
}

#fixed-side {
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

#fixed-top {
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

#fixed-bottom {
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

#relative-wrapped-absolute {
    top: 8px;
    position: relative;
}

#relative-wrapped-absolute div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}

.offset {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#grid {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.grid-line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    font-size: 8px;
    height: 9px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery you can do this by calling .position() function. Like:

```
$('#mydiv').position().left;
$('#mydiv').position().top;
```

This is the most reliable way, since it already calculates the position checking the CSS of elements and its parents.

You can see the full implementation here:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js at line 9077

Answer (score 3):

Do you need the x and y for a specific element.

```
$("#bnElement").offset().left;
$("#bnElement").offset().top;
```

Just have a look at the following post [jQuery x y document coordinates of DOM object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002934/jquery-x-y-document-coordinates-of-dom-object)
regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you. ?!

HTML

```
    <div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
```

CSS

```
div { padding: 50px;}
p { margin-left:10px; }
```

JS

```
    var p = $("p:first");
    var position = p.position();
    $("p:last").text( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bZezzz/TvMMv/

Answer (score 0):

**Using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)() method**

```
    var domTree = [];
var allelems = document.querySelectorAll(tagsCheck ); // for all tags use --> '*'

for(var i = 0; i < allTags.length; i++){
    console.log(i+'  '+'Tag : '+ allTags[i].nodeName+'#'+allTags[i].id);  // getPath(allTags[i]);

    getPosition(allTags[i]);
    console.log('Coordinates  : {top   : '+allTags[i].getBoundingClientRect().top+', left   : '+allTags[i].getBoundingClientRect().left+' } ');

    console.log('Dimensions offset       :  {width : '+allTags[i].offsetWidth+', height : '+allTags[i].offsetHeight+' } ');
    console.log('Dimensions style  Q     :  {width : '+allTags[i].style.width+', height : '+allTags[i].style.height+' } '); 

    var singleTag = [];
    var jsonData = getTagInfo(allelems[i]); //singleTag.push(getFullXPath(allelems[i]));
    singleTag.push(jsonData);
    domTree.push(singleTag);
console.log(singleTag);

}
function getTagInfo(element){ 
    return '{ \"Xpath\": \"'+ getFullXPath(element) + '\", \"left\": '+element.getBoundingClientRect().left+',\"top\":  '+element.getBoundingClientRect().top+
    ',\"width\": '+element.offsetWidth+',\"height\" : '+element.offsetHeight+'}';
}
```

**Using [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName)() and [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)()**

```
function getElementDimensions(tagsCheck){
    var allElem = document.getElementsByTagName('*'); 
    for(i = 0, j = 0; i < allElem.length; i++) { 
        var elemstyle= window.getComputedStyle(allElem[i], null);
        if( tagsCheck.indexOf( allElem[i].tagName ) > -1 ){
            console.log(i+'  '+'Tag : '+allElem[i].tagName+'[@id : '+allElem[i].id);
            console.log('Dimensions style  E     :  {width : '+elemstyle.width+', height : '+elemstyle.height+' } '); 
        }
    }
}
```

*[position](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/get_element_position_using_javascript.htm) and [XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510576/find-an-element-by-text-and-get-xpath-selenium-webdriver-junit/32201731#32201731) of an HTML element*

```
function getPosition(element){ 
    var xPosition = 0; 
    var yPosition = 0; 
        while(element) { 
            xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
            yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop); 
        element = element.offsetParent; 
        }
    console.log('GetPosition  : {top   : '+yPosition+', left   : '+xPosition+' } ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really liked [jquery.simulate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate) implementation

```
function findCorner(elem) {
    var offset,
        document = $(elem.ownerDocument);
    elem = $(elem);
    offset = elem.offset();

    return {
        x: offset.left - document.scrollLeft(),
        y: offset.top - document.scrollTop()
    };
}
```

seems to capture a lot of scenarios. 
it brings you the position relative to screen.. so if I scrolled, some items may be in negative position. which is useful for automated tests that use drag & drop.

You can easily wrap it with jquery for cool syntax like so

```
$.fn.findCorner = function(){
    if ( this.length > 1 ) {
        return this.map(function(){ return findCorner(this); })
    } else {
        return findCorner(this[0]);
    }
};
```

and so do `$('div').findCorner()`..